# Отключить прокручивание колесиком мыши в ScrollPane - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jscrollpane

Как отключить прокручивание колесиком мыши в ScrollPane. Кто нибудь залезал глубоко в код родителя?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461643/javafx-disable-scrolling-by-mousewheel-in-scrollpane

Answer (score 2):

```
scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, event -> event.consume());
```